# Kendo tree view and tree dropdown - current selection and synchronization of changes

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

This snippet
http://dojo.telerik.com/UGaFucez

has two controls - tree view and tree dropdown. These 2 controls are sharing a data source so they display same tree. But the puzzling thing is that they also seem to share the currently selected value and when you change selection in one field, it also changes in the other.
HOW? Data source is not supposed to share currently selected value (there is no notion of currently selected value). and there is no MVVM binding set up. But somehow the fields stay synchronized - can anybody explain why and what is behind that? And how can i disconnect this dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the experienced behaviour is excepted. The DataSource objects hold the states for the records. In other words, we keep the expanded, selected, checked ... and so on states in the kendo data source object. This could be used as an enhancement in the majority of scenarios. For example, you should trigger only one delete/create/update request and have the data applied in all of the associated widgets. However, indeed for some scenarios in is not suitable. For your case, you can have different instances of the DataSource and have the widgets populated with them:

```
  var data= [
        {
          text: "Furniture", items: [
            { text: "Tables & Chairs" },
            { text: "Sofas" },
            { text: "Occasional Furniture" }
          ]
        },
        {
          text: "Decor", items: [
            { text: "Bed Linen" },
            { text: "Curtains & Blinds" },
            { text: "Carpets" }
          ]
        }
      ]      

  var ds1 = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
      data: data
    });      
  var ds2 = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
      data: data
    });  


  var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource:ds1 
  }).data("kendoTreeView");

  $('#treeField').kendoDropDownTree({
    dataSource: ds2
  });
```

Here is a dojo example on the matter:  http://dojo.telerik.com/@nenchef/ucapaTeT